# boolean character compare - trying to compare three characters at once in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to write a piece of code to simulate text messaging on an old keypad.  2 = a,b,c 3 = def etc.

I can read the string and pull out the character but I am trying to develop an elegant way in Java of mapping the character to the number.

I could use the `Character.compare`. But I am going to have to compare my character with the full alphabet.

```
compareOneTwo = Character.compare(ch[r], 'a'); etc
```

I would rather use a `Boolean` function that compares three characters at once using an "or"

```
if(ch[r] = 'a'||'b'||'c') {
```

But I am struggling - with getting this to work.

I appreciate that this is basic and probably a silly mistake but we all have to start somewhere...

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So just to clarify: Do you want for example hit the 1 twice and get a `b`. And if you hit it four times you get a `d`? Or do you just need a way to tell which letter would have which number on the keypad?

Comment: I don't think it's a good solution, but `char c = ch[r]; if (c == 'a' || c == 'b' || c == 'c')` would work

Comment: eckes is right! each `||` has to be a complete comparison! Also, by using `=` instead of `==`, you're  *assigning* 'a' to chr[r], instead of *comparing* value at chr[r] to 'a'. Anyway, you can't compare one value to *multiple* things with the `||` or `&&` operators!  If it was C what you did is "Assign 'a' to chr[r], if result non-zero, or value of 'b' is non-zero, or value of 'c' non-zero, do the action of your `if()`. In Java zero/non-zero are not true/false like in C,  Java compiler shows error? Always provide essential details of the problem and the errors so people have to guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said it yourself, you are trying to find a way to **map** the characters to the numbers, so use a map!

```
Map<Character, Integer> characters = new HashMap<>();
characters.put('a', 2);
characters.put('b', 2);
characters.put('c', 2);
characters.put('d', 3);
...
characters.put('z', 0);

Integer number = characters.get('a');
System.out.println(number); // Will print '2'
```

The initial setup is a bit more code since you have to specify the whole alphabet, but store it in a static variable and it'll be done once for your whole application.

This will definitely yield the best performances in terms of speed, and regarding memory usage, it's only 26 characters and as many integers, so negligible :)

Another advantage is that it is easy to update, if you need to handle a new character like `*`, just add one row to the map and it's done!

Comment: `This will definitely yield the best performances in terms of speed, and regarding memory usage` - that's probably not entirely true although in many cases the differences should be negligible. In fact if characters a-z should be "mapped" only, a simple `int[]` containing the numbers and a method that converts the character into the appropriate index (e.g. `int index = c - 'a';`) would probably be faster and require less memory ;) - it wouldn't be as flexible though, e.g. adding `*` might require more work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the OR operator as you wish.

You do have other alternatives if you don't want to have many conditions connected by OR (`||`) operators.

You can create a `Set` and use `contains`:

```
if (Set.of('a','b','c').contains(ch[r])) {}
```

Or you can use a range of characters if you need to check for a consecutive range:

```
if (ch[r] >= 'a' && ch[r] <= 'c') {}
```